# Slow web page speed

Tags: html, css

My webpage turns white for like a second before loading page and it does not seem as if all the background images load together(either that or they are out of sink). I did some research found something about sprite(didnt work) and also changed pic from jpg->png->gif and back(i even crossed a few) could someone please help me with this problem. ps. dont mind the bunch of "king" they are just place holders to see how the background spans out.
    -thank you

CSS:

```
    * {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;

        list-style-type:none;
        }
        html{

        background-image:url("Aba2.jpg");
        -webkit-background-size:cover;
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        -o-background-size:cover;
        background-size:cover;
        text-align:center;

        }
        header, section, footer, aside, nav,article{display:block}

        #Wrapper{

         width:1100px;
         margin:20px auto;


        }
        #H_wrap{
         padding:10px;
         height:150px;
         background-image:url("Abracci1.jpg");
         background-repeat:repeat-x;
         -webkit-background-size:cover;
         -moz-background-size:cover;
         -o-background-size:cover;
         background-size:cover;

        }

        #M_head{
        padding:10px;
        font:italic bold 34px/30px "Times New Roman" Times, arial;
        Text-align:center;
        color:#000000;
        text-shadow:2px 2px #999999;
        text-decoration:underline;


        }

        #N_bar {
        padding:40px;
        text-align:center;
        word-spacing:6em;
        font:italic bold 25px/30px "Times New Roman" Times, arial;
        text-shadow:3px 3px grey;


        }

         a:link.NB{
         color:white;
        }
         a:visited.NB{
         color:black;
        }
         a:hover.NB{
         color:GOLD;
        }
         a:active.NB{
         color:#423243;
        }


        #N_bar li{
        display:inline-block;
        }

        #M_section{
        background-image:url("Aba3.jpg");
        background-position:center;
        padding:20px;
        -webkit-background-size:cover;
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        -o-background-size:cover;
        background-size:cover;
        }
 END CSS.     
HTML:
        <!Doctype html>
    <html lang="eng">
    <head>
     <meta charset="uft-8"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="Abracci_main.css"/>
    </head>
    <html>
    <body>
       <div id="Wrapper">
        <div id="H_wrap">

             <header id="M_head">
             <h1>Abracci</h1>
             </header>


             <nav id="N_bar">
                 <ul>

                     <li><a class="NB" href="https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/">Men</a></li>
                     <li><a class="NB" href="#">Women</a></li>
                     <li><a class="NB" href="#">Children</a></li>
                     <li><a class="NB" href="#">Apparel</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </nav>
             </div>
             <section id="M_section">
                  <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li> <li>King</li>

             </section>
             <aside id="M_aside">

             </aside>
             <footer id="M_footer">

             </footer>

          </div>



    </body>
    </html>

        }
END HTML.
```

Comment: You could provide use with an example? What images aren't loading, is the file name correct? There isn't enough information for us to know what the problem could be.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. my webpage is offline so i cant test speed or "validate" it but im pretty sure that its very slow, because when i refresh or switch link the screen goes blank, then the words appear then the backgrounds kick in. i was wondering if there was a way to stop this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [validator,](http://validator.w3.org/) and the browser developer tools in chrome, firefox or internet explorer. The net tab will tell you exactly what is going on.
Please fix the formatting of your question (missing html tag, extra }, etc